Pull weight via stepper motor and have it snap back via gravity after some distance
Total newbie here with no understanding of mechanical concepts. I'm completely lost and looking to get guidance on what direction to look into next.
I have a stepper motor and some thread and a weight. I want to pull the weight up some distance (say, whatever 5 rotations of the motor equates to) and have it fall down through gravity afterwards.
Some limitations though: I can only tell the motor to turn forwards or backwards for some duration, ie I cannot guarantee a full rotation,  (example: power loss mid rotation).
Essentially I want to tell the motor: "spin forwards for 9 seconds. This should result in the weight being pulled up and fall back down. I can tell the motor to spin backwards for 1 second or so as well, so if that makes it any easier, feel free to use that somehow.
I need some way to uncouple the motor from the winch based on the number of motor rotations or potentially a marker on the thread, but I can't figure out how..
I have access to a 3d printer.

what is the weight?

can the motor offer some braking when the weight is dropping?

how far is the drop?

Drop is at most 20 cm, hopefully

The weight drops onto the floor, no need to brake

asking if the motor is allowed to exert drag on the weight when it drops

have you considered using an arm instead of a reel ... attach a cam to the motor ... use cam to lift arm ... at end of cam rotation. the arm drops ... weight attached to the end of arm ... think of a fishing rod

A long arm is probably not possible here because the weight should be lifted a potentially infinite amount

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You state that the motor can turn in only one direction; is there a mechanical limitation or a programming one?
Stepper motors typically require power to be applied to hold position, as well as to move/rotate. Your stepper drivers should support releasing the power to the motor or set it in position.
To get the weight to drop will depend on the mass of the item as well as the general resistance to rotation of the stepper motor.
One could consider that a motor "weak" enough to allow the mass to fall when power is removed is probably going to be strong enough to lift a small weight, while a more powerful motor would match better with a heavier item.

one directional motor is a choice I made, because if the whole thing was possible using only one motor direction it would make programming a bit easier. Updated the title to reflect that, ty!

Using a weak enough stepper motor is probably not possible here. For one, I already have these specific ones and would like to use them, but more importantly, the gravity pull-back should be (ideally) instant, so when the weight falls it releases maximum energy.

A weight falling in gravity doesn't do anything "instantly", so you need to be a bit more clear about what your actual requirement is.

The weight should achieve it's maximum force when hitting the ground, IE it shouldn't be slowed down arbitrarily by friction or the stepper motor

Here are gear train examples that engage when driven in one direction, but disengage when driven in reverse.
Example 1 : Helical , more robust
https://youtu.be/iL8gOluzKUk
Example 2 : Spur
https://youtu.be/X_fbDb4F5ZU

Edit, my initial answer is below.
Use a gear train with a spring loaded clutch engagement mechanism?
The gear train should split into one part which winds the string / rope up, and another which advances a mechanism to disengage the clutch.

Thanks you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

You can attach your stepper motor to a disk with one tooth, like a cam, say turning clockwise. This cam engages a shaft located on the right with one nutch which glides up and down in a guide rail while lifting the weight.
As the disk turns the cam pulls the shaft up while turning until the cam turns out and away from the notch of the shaft. The shaft and weight fall and the cam turns one full tern and rests next to the notch that has fallen, ready for your next command.
Edit


I don't really understand what you mean here. Could you please create a mini illustration using pen and paper or smth?

@CiriousJoker, I added a sketch. Check my edited answer, please.

Ah thanks, now I understand. I'm afraid this won't work though, I want to hang the object from a string if possible and this design limits the distance I can pull it up by the length of the shaft :( Thanks for your efforts though!
